# convert Series to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, categorical-data

I created a dataframe 'x'

I wanted to create another dataframe y which consists of values of feature 'wheat_type' from dataframe x

so i executed the code

```
y=X.loc[:, 'wheat_type']
```

when I ran the following command

```
y['wheat_type'] = y.wheat_type("category").cat.codes
```

I got following error

> 'Series' object has no attribute 'wheat_type'

on executing type(X),I got

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

and on executing type(y),I got

```
 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Is there possible way to covert y into a dataframe.If not,please tell me how to create required dataframe y from x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'wheat_type':[5,7,3]})
print (X)
   wheat_type
0           5
1           7
2           3

#create DataFrame by subset
y=X[['wheat_type']]

#cast to category and get codes
y['wheat_type'] = y.wheat_type.astype("category").cat.codes
print (y)
   wheat_type
0           1
1           2
2           0
```

If there are multiple columns, better is use `to_frame` as pointed [`Ami`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38913459/2901002):

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'wheat_type':[5,7,3], 'z':[4,7,9]})
print (X)
   wheat_type  z
0           5  4
1           7  7
2           3  9

y = X['wheat_type'].to_frame()

#cast to category and get codes
y['wheat_type'] = y.wheat_type.astype("category").cat.codes
print (y)
   wheat_type
0           1
1           2
2           0
```

---

Another solution for creating new DataFrame is by subset and [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
y = X[['wheat_type']].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem.In other code I ran a simple 'df = pd.read_csv()' code but when I executed df.dtypes() I got same error ''Series' object is not callable'.How to fix that?

Comment: You need only omit `()` - `print df.dtypes`

Comment: See [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's a special method for that - [`pd.Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4)})

In [3]: df.a
Out[3]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [4]: df.a.to_frame()
Out[4]: 
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Comment: I used the above command and when i execute 'type(y)' I now get the output '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>'.But when I execute the code 'y['wheat_type'] = y.wheat_type("category").cat.codes',I am still getting the error ''Series' object is not callable'.Any idea why?

Comment: @SHIVAMGOYAL - see my answer, you need cast to `category`.

Comment: Well, Jezrael beat me to answering your question :-). In any case, I verified that `df.a.to_frame().a.astype('category')` works.